# ListView items aren't clickable when I show a LinearLayout as sibling

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, floating-action-button

I'm having trouble with a ListView.
Basically, i have this hidden ListView to be shown on a TextView click.
This works ok.
When I click on a Item of the ListView, i would like to show another Layout(containing a TextView & a FloatingButton). 
The problem is that when I show the LinearLayout, I can't click on the ListItem anymore. Any suggestions?

Here's some code: 
**Layout.xml**

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/meal_insertion_meals_portions_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_insertion_location"
            android:layout_above="@id/meal_insertion_add_container"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/meal_insertion_add_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/meal_insertion_add_meal_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/meal_insertion_add_meal_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/diary.meal.insertion.aliment.add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment.java**

```
mealSelector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectorList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    selectorList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mealLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    selectorList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mealLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        selectorList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                mealSelector.setText(t1.getText());
                selectorList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mealLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addLayoutContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


         }

    );
```

Comment: "The problem is that when I show the LinearLayout, I can't click on the ListItem anymore." - Aren't you hiding the `ListView` when you click on an item and show the `LinearLayout`? `selectorList.setVisibility(View.GONE);` Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: If I click on the TextView again, I'll show the listView again, and I may want to select some any other item. The problem is that Items are not longer clickable when addLayoutContainer is visible.

Comment: Ah, OK. Are you sure something's not covering your `ListView` somehow, and blocking the clicks?

Comment: Sure, as you can see from the layout file, the ListView is setted to be ABOVE the containerLayout

Comment: Yeah, well, `RelativeLayout`s can behave counter to expectation. And that's assuming you've actually got those `View`s in a `RelativeLayout`. You didn't post the whole layout. Anyway, toggling a `ListView`'s visibility shouldn't affect its `OnItemClickListener`, so unless you're doing something else to it in code that you've not posted, I would have to guess that it's something to do with the layout's behavior.

Comment: I just set an adapter for that List. The problem is that every's fine untill I make that ContainerLayout VISIBLE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114848/discussion-between-luca-nicoletti-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS NOT THE RIGHT SOLUTION** - Just a workaround:

I just hide the `ContainerLayout` again when I show the `ListView`.
This let me clicks on Items again.

> **AGAIN**: Still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions,
change listview, android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="match_parent", in addition try with removing android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" from Floating button.